# Sitecore Autofac - Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I would like to use Autofac in my Sitecore project with Solr,
I have set next code to global.asax

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.AutoFacIntegration.AutoFacApplication" %>
```

but i see an error

```
Method not found: 'Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac.Core.IModule)'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac.Core.IModule)'
```

I have checked AutoFac version and it is correct 3.5.2 like in *Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.AutoFacIntegration*

What should I do to set up it correct in term of Sitecore.

Comment: Have you definitely included both Autofac related DLL's from the Solr Support Package? -- `AutofacContrib.SolrNet.dll` and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.AutoFacIntegration.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens because Sitecore's Solr support package relies on an old Autofac version (3.1.5 or earlier) where the method `builder.RegisterModule()` was still defined in `Autofac.RegistrationExtensions`. Newer Autofac versions have a similar method defined in the class `Autofac.ModuleRegistrationExtensions`.

Without Sitecore recompiling the Solr/Autofac integration dlls, unfortunately, there are only two ways around this:

1. Use another DI library;
2. Write your own Solr/Autofac integration.

This issue is still present in the Solr support package shipped with Sitecore 8.2.

I have registered this issue with Sitecore Support.

**Edit:** Sitecore replied that the support of Autofac 3.2 and later is on the wish list. To track the status of this request, you can use the reference number **94626**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you removed all the Lucene config files and added in all the solr config files in the App_Config/Include.

You will also need to drop in all the Solr Dlls as shown below.

[image]